# Retreving Google Calendar Events using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Am trying to get all the events in my calendar and i come up with the below code. But the problem is am getting only one event from the calender.(i.e, event which is nearby). can someone please help me where am going wrong and suggest me a way. Thanks in advance.

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars();
Logger.log("Length is :" +cal.length);
for(var i=0; i<cal.length;i++)
{
var cid = cal[i].getEvents(now, later) ;
Logger.log(cid[i].getTitle());
}
```

Comment: What are the values you are giving for now, later?? Can you check in API explorer event.list https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list with time min and timemax values same as now and later to check the results..

Comment: now = new Date(); later = new Date(now.getTime() + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000));  this input doesnt retrieve the event between, now and 2hours later. is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get all the events if you don't know the end date.  There is no way to determine the end date.  You *can* retrieve all the events for today:

```
// Determines how many events are happening today.
var today = new Date();
var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today);
Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);
  for(var i=0; i<cal.length;i++) {
  var eventTitle = events[i].getTitle();
  Logger.log('eventTitle: ' + eventTitle);
}
```

You could set an end date that was many years into the past I suppose.

```
var now = new Date();
var later = new Date(2010, 0, 1);
```

Sets the `later` date to Jan. 1st, 2010

Comment: Thanks Sandy Good. Your suggestion and code helps me.